# Javascript and querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html

When you click on an address, it should change to the appropriate picture and the background of the name of the address should be darkened. I'm trying to make it so when you click on another address, the previous address isn't darkened anymore. The pictures were switching when the addresses were clicked, but when I added the if statement with the querySelectorAll, it stopped switching, and the background of the previous address doesn't go back to what it was before.

Code in question:

```
function map(x) {
  x.classList.add("active");
  for (let i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++){
    if (x.innerHTML == addresses[i]){
      document.getElementById("map").setAttribute("src", mapPicSRC[i]);
    }
    else{
      if (document.querySelectorAll("#locations ul:nth-child(" + i+1 ")")[0].classList.contains("active")) {
        document.querySelectorAll("#locations ul:nth-child(" + i+1 ")")[0].classList.remove("active");
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="locations">
  <!-- ul inserted with js -->
  <div id="mapCrop">
    <img src="img/location1.png" id="map">
  </div>
</section>
```

HTML inserted via Javascript:

```
const addresses = ["1 Main Street", "1 Lincoln Street", "1 Jefferson Street"];
const mapPicSRC = ["img/location1.png", "img/location2.png", "img/location3.png"];

const addressList = document.createElement("ul");
document.getElementById("locations").insertBefore(addressList, document.getElementById("mapCrop"));

for (let i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++){
  let item = document.createElement("li")
  addressList.appendChild(item);
  item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(addresses[i]));
  item.setAttribute("onclick", "map(this)");
  if (i == 0){
    item.classList.add("active");
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
#locations{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  display:block;
  padding:0;
}

li{
  border:2px solid black;
  padding:8px;
  color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family:"PT Serif", "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-size:18px;
  background:rgb(52, 32, 22);
  transition:background-color 0.2s ease-out;
  padding:10px;
  padding-right:150px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of using `querySelectorAll()` if you're then going to use the `[0]` subscript? That's the same as using `querySelector()`.

Comment: To make the previous element not darkened, select the element with the `active` class and remove the class. Then add the `active` class to the new selection.

Comment: `document.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");`

Answer (score 0):

You can store the previous active item and remove the class from that element before adding the class to the next clicked item.

```js
let prevActive;
for (let i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++){
  // ...
  if (i == 0){
    item.classList.add("active");
    prevActive = item;
  }
}
function map(x) {
  prevActive.classList.remove('active');
  x.classList.add("active");
  prevActive = x;
  // ...
  // remove the else branch with document.querySelectorAll
}
```

You could also select the active element with `document.querySelector`.

```js
function map(x) {
    document.querySelector('#locations li.active').classList.remove('active');
    x.classList.add("active");
    // ...
}
```